# When using Keras, is it possible to figure out what tensorflow methods are being invoked?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to figure out why an ML model is failing and want to see every single method call in the tensorflow backend. How do I do this?

Comment: Read the source code. - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras

Comment: Is it possible that [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) fits your needs?